# Running Python script file exported from QGIS Graphical Modeller in external terminal

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-processing, qgis-modeler, standalone

For instance, I have created a simple graphical modeler which gives NDVI as an output when the NIR band and Red Band are provided:

[image: Graphical Model]

I exported the Python script using 'Export as script algorithm' in the graphical modeler and the script is attached below:

```py
"""
Model exported as python.
Name : model
Group : 
With QGIS : 32203
"""

from qgis.core import QgsProcessing
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingAlgorithm
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterRasterLayer
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterRasterDestination
from qgis.core import QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem
import processing


class Model(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):

    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterRasterLayer('nirband', 'NIR Band', defaultValue=None))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterRasterLayer('redband', 'Red Band', defaultValue=None))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterRasterDestination('Ndvi', 'ndvi', createByDefault=True, defaultValue=None))

    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, model_feedback):
        # Use a multi-step feedback, so that individual child algorithm progress reports are adjusted for the
        # overall progress through the model
        feedback = QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback(1, model_feedback)
        results = {}
        outputs = {}

        # NDVI Calculation
        alg_params = {
            'CELLSIZE': 0,
            'CRS': QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:3857'),
            'EXPRESSION': '("NIR Band@1"  - "Red Band@1" )  /  ( "NIR Band@1" + "Red Band@1" ) ',
            'EXTENT': parameters['nirband'],
            'LAYERS': parameters['nirband'],
            'OUTPUT': parameters['Ndvi']
        }
        outputs['NdviCalculation'] = processing.run('qgis:rastercalculator', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
        results['Ndvi'] = outputs['NdviCalculation']['OUTPUT']
        return results

    def name(self):
        return 'model'

    def displayName(self):
        return 'model'

    def group(self):
        return ''

    def groupId(self):
        return ''

    def createInstance(self):
        return Model()
```

I saved this file as `ndvi.py`. Now I would like to run this Python file in terminal (not in QGIS python console). I created a new virtual environment and installed all the necessary packages.

Now I am not sure how can I use `ndvi.py` or simply how can I use the class or function above to obtain the output. Could anyone tell me about this?

Comment: Hello Taras, I am dealing with a very simillar issue. Did you find a solution how to run QGIS geoprocessing tasks from external script?